# Cisco SPA112 ATA only rings half the time

Tags: voip, sip, analog

I have a Cisco SPA112 ATA Unit which I have set up to connect to an online SIP account (no LAN Asterisk servers in use) and I have this issue where sometimes the unit will not ring when someone calls and sometimes it does.. I can always call OUT on the unit however. I have seen something along the lines of "Next Registration: 89 Seconds" on the Status page but beyond that I am stumped.. If anyone knows how to fix this its greatly appreciated.. we need this thing to work as a fulling functioning telephone line and that isn't going to cut it..

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by enabling the "NAT Keep Alive" option.